# What is causing this memory leak with Tkinter canvas?

Tags: python, image, canvas, memory-leaks, tkinter

Using the following code, the memory usage increases rapidly as the asteroid images move across the screen, then stops increasing as the images move beyond the edges of the canvas. Could anyone explain why this happens? I would like to keep an image moving on the screen indefinitely in my program, but it eventually eats up all the memory on my system.

I am new to python, Tk, and Tkinter. Is there something obvious I am missing about canvas.move(...) or canvas.update()? Should I be using a different method to accomplish this task? Thanks.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW
import Image 
import ImageTk
from random import random

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas = Canvas(f, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("asteroid01.png"))
sprites = []
for i in range(10):
    sprites.append(canvas.create_image(50*random(), 50*random(), image=image))


vel = {'x': 1, 'y': 1}
while True:
    for s in sprites:
        canvas.move(s, vel['x'], vel['y'])
    canvas.update()
```

EDIT: Calling update seems to a bad practice, so here is the code changed as suggested. However, the program still consumes memory while the images are moving and does not release it until the window is closed.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Frame, BOTH, NW
import Image 
import ImageTk
from random import random

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)
f.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
canvas = Canvas(f, width=1000, height=1000)
canvas.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("asteroid01.png"))
sprites = []
for i in range(10):
    sprites.append(canvas.create_image(50*random(), 50*random(), image=image))

vel = {'x': 1, 'y': 1}

def move():
    for s in sprites:
        canvas.move(s, vel['x'], vel['y'])
    canvas.after(10, move)

move()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is because you are calling update in a tight loop. Every call to update is effectively creating a new event loop. That is probably what is eating up your memory.

Instead, change your logic to look something like this (untested, but should be pretty close to right):

```
def move():
    for s in sprites:
        canvas.move(s, vel['x'], vel['y'])
    canvas.after(10, move)
move()
```

You call move the first time, then it causes itself to be called again sometime in the future.  The magnitude of the number (in milliseconds) determines how fast the objects move.

If you want to be able to stop the animation you can set a flag, and then check for that flag each time before calling `after`.

Comment: I still need to call canvas.update() inside move(), though right? Doing this I still have the memory leak, even with after set to 1000. Can you explain what you mean about an "event loop"? What event loop does update() create? I know root.mainloop() will start an event loop looking for interaction with the window. Does canvas.update() not just redraw the canvas?

Comment: @user487100: no. As a general rule of thumb you should _never_ call `update`. And no, `canvas.update()` does _not_ just update the canvas. It creates a new event loop, just like `mainloop` does.  An event loop is just an internal function that looks like "while True: wait_for_event(); process_event()". When you call `mainloop()` it does that, and every time you call `update()` it does that, so you end up with a loop inside a loop inside a loop inside a loop...

Comment: I didn't realize it would redraw without me calling update. I'm still seeing a memory leak. I'll update the code I'm using in my question. Can you take a look?

Comment: What is making you believe it has a memory leak? Are you absolutely certain that the above code and _only_ the above code is giving you a memory leak? I ran it on OSX with python 2.7 and didn't see a memory leak after letting it run for a couple of hours.

Comment: No I'm not absolutely sure, but I figured it was more likely to be programmer (me) error than something wrong with Python. I'm also running on OSX (10.7.4). I'm using python 2.7.1 and the program grows by about 20MB in the time it takes the sprites to move across the screen.

Comment: @user487100: does it continue to grow if you leave it for a hour, or does it hit a high water mark and stay there? FWIW, that program took about 20MB on my machine and then stayed at that mark for an hour or two.